# javascript : how to link categories to date in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, time-series

fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/jaiminsoni/38v7jfs3/12/

```
     current = 1246406400000;
    arrayShifts = [];
    arrayTimestampActual = [];

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      arrayShifts[i] = current + (i * 6 * 3600 * 1000);
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= 18; i++) {
      arrayTimestampActual[i] = current + (i * 1 * 3600 * 1000);
    }


    var
      color3 = [
        [arrayShifts[0], 27, 40],

        [arrayShifts[1] - 60000, 27, 40],
        [arrayShifts[1], 30, 50],

        [arrayShifts[2] - 60000, 30, 50],
        [arrayShifts[2], 40, 60],

        [arrayShifts[3] - 60000, 40, 60],
        [arrayShifts[3], 45, 65],

        [arrayShifts[4] - 60000, 45, 65],
      ],
      color2 = [
        [arrayShifts[0], 14.3, 27],

        /* [1246492800000, 14.3, 27], */
        [arrayShifts[1] - 60000, 14.3, 27],
        [arrayShifts[1], 20, 30],

        [arrayShifts[2] - 60000, 20, 30],
        [arrayShifts[2], 28, 40],

        [arrayShifts[3] - 60000, 28, 40],
        [arrayShifts[3], 30, 45],

        [arrayShifts[4] - 60000, 30, 45],
      ],
      color1 = [
        [arrayShifts[0], 0, 14.3],

        [arrayShifts[1] - 60000, 0, 14.3],
        [arrayShifts[1], 0, 20],

        [arrayShifts[2] - 60000, 0, 20],
        [arrayShifts[2], 0, 28],

        [arrayShifts[3] - 60000, 0, 28],
        [arrayShifts[3], 0, 30],

        [arrayShifts[4] - 60000, 0, 30],

      ],
      value = [
        [arrayTimestampActual[0], 10],
        [arrayTimestampActual[1], 20],
        [arrayTimestampActual[2], 25],
        [arrayTimestampActual[3], 23.8],
        [arrayTimestampActual[4], 20],
        [arrayTimestampActual[5], 12],
        [arrayTimestampActual[6], 37],
        [arrayTimestampActual[7], 23.8],
        [arrayTimestampActual[8], 35],
        [arrayTimestampActual[9], 15],
        [arrayTimestampActual[10], 22],
        [arrayTimestampActual[11], 23.8],
        [arrayTimestampActual[12], 35],
        [arrayTimestampActual[13], 38],
        [arrayTimestampActual[14], 25],
        [arrayTimestampActual[15], 30],
        [arrayTimestampActual[16], 35],
        [arrayTimestampActual[17], 27],
        [arrayTimestampActual[18], 38]
      ];


    var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

      title: {
        text: ''
      },

      xAxis: [{
        type: 'datetime'
      },
      {
      categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
                    opposite: true
      }],

      yAxis: {
        min: 0,

        title: {
          text: null
        }
      },

      tooltip: {
        crosshairs: true,
        shared: true,
        // valueSuffix: '°C'
      },
      chart: {
        backgroundColor: '#f4f4f4',

      },

      /*  legend: {
       }, */

      series: [{
          name: 'Value',
          data: value,
          zIndex: 1,
          marker: {
            fillColor: 'white',
            lineWidth: 2,
            lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
          }
        }, {
          name: 'color1',
          data: color1,
          type: 'arearange',
          lineWidth: 0,
          //  linkedTo: ':previous',
          color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
          fillOpacity: 0.3,
          zIndex: 0,
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          }
        },
        {
          name: 'color2',
          data: color2,
          type: 'arearange',
          lineWidth: 0,
          //    linkedTo: ':previous',
          color: '#FFC200',
          fillOpacity: 0.3,
          zIndex: 0,
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          }
        },
        {
          name: 'color3',
          data: color3,
          type: 'arearange',
          lineWidth: 0,
          /*       linkedTo: ':previous', */
          color: '#f01515',
          fillOpacity: 0.3,
          zIndex: 0,
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    var maxY = chart.yAxis[0].max;
    var color4 = [
      [arrayShifts[0], 40, maxY],

      [arrayShifts[1] - 60000, 40, maxY],
      [arrayShifts[1], 50, maxY],

      [arrayShifts[2] - 60000, 50, maxY],
      [arrayShifts[2], 60, maxY],

      [arrayShifts[3] - 60000, 60, maxY],
      [arrayShifts[3], 65, maxY],

      [arrayShifts[4] - 60000, 65, maxY],
    ];
    chart.addSeries({
      name: 'color4',
      //showInLegend: false,
      data: color4,
      type: 'arearange'
    });

chart.yAxis[0].update({
  max: maxY
});
```

Charts has line -> value: hourly values 
 which is 00:00:00, 01:00:00, 02:00:00, etc.

it has arearange -> color1, color2, color3 and color4 : every 6 hours values 
which is 00:00:00, 05:59:59, 06:00:00, 11:59:59, 12:00:00, 17:59:59, etc.

i'm trying to add second x-axis : category  : as

00:00:00 to 05:59:59 : cate_1 
06:00:00 to 11:59:59 : cate_2 
12:00:00 to 17:59:59 : cate_3 
18:00:00 to 23:59:59 : cate_4

is there any way to do this? I couldn't find any solution for how to link category with datetime?

Comment: Can you make an example of what you expect to have if this works? A simple mockup would do.

Comment: Think the poster wants a secondary xAxis labeled with category names at 6 hour intervals (First 6 hours is labelled Cat 1, next 6 is Cat 2, etc)

Comment: @EllaRyan, yes you are right, i want secondary axis as cat_1 for date 00:00:00 to 05:59:59, cat_2 for date 06:00:00 to 11:59:59, means categories linked to datetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Add a second xAxis with the `categories` option set with an array of categories (Cat 1, Cat 2, etc as needed)
- Set all your current series to use the original axis ( add option `xAxis: 0` to each series)
- Add a new hidden series that uses the new axis (`xAxis: 1`). You can hide the series by setting `showInLegend: false`, `marker: {enabled: false }` and `lineWidth: 0`
- The data in the new series is arbitrary data (so just set each point to zero) but you need to have the same number of items in the series as you have categories (so for 4 categories `data: [[0, 0],[1, 0],[2, 0],[3, 0]]` )

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/38v7jfs3/56/

I've hardcoded the four categories in the example. Your code will have to calculate the number of categories you need based on your data.
The categories are not actually linked to a datetime concept, you simply need to make sure you have the right number of categories (ie figure out how many 6 hour intervals there are in the total time period covered by the graph and add that many categories)

Comment: thanks!, this is you have done it for one day, but it might require for more than one day, then 4 categories need to be repeat based on time interval, basically this categories would be part of day. Four part in one day, even though days are different categories would be same for each day :)

Comment: @Soni007 Yes, as I mentioned you'll have to alter the categories based on your time period

Comment: i have added one datetime,  now it is 1st july 00:00:00 to 2nd july 05:59:59, ("this date range assumed to be selected by datetime picker") but categories divides the whole range into four parts INSTEAD, cat 1 to cat 4 and new date comes again cat 1. hope you understand Ella :) here is the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/jaiminsoni/38v7jfs3/78/)

Comment: [update] (https://jsfiddle.net/jaiminsoni/q4fv3ywo/8/), i tried to alter categories based on date, but what if start date is 1st july 06:00:00 and end date is 2nd july 18:00:00 then shifts will be : shift 2, shift 3, shift 4, shift 1, shift 2, shift 3, how do i code that? this works with if start of the day is 00:00:00, using for loop to update categories and related data which would be null :)